# How to connect two UI Elements by swiping? WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, swipe

Actually I'm developing a simple game. In my game, I need to connect multiple buttons by swiping. But I don't know which events should I use to do that. What I want is kind of similar to Candy Crush game.

Please help me out guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Handling pointer input on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/handle-pointer-input#Pointer_events), specifically the [PointerPressed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208971), [PointerMoved](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208970), and [PointerReleased](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208972) events. You can keep track of the pointer information by making use of the `PointerRoutedEventArgs` argument passed in those events, including checking whether the pointer belongs to a mouse or if it is brought about by touching the screen. There are some good examples in each article.

Comment: Thank you so much @owen-d for the article. I still have one problem though. PointerEntered event is perfect for my case. But I also need an event like PointerStarted, though there is no event of this name. Can you refer me a similar event like this?

Comment: Perhaps PointerPressed is what you're looking for? The description is: "Occurs when the pointer indicates a press action (such as a touch down, mouse button down, pen down, or touchpad button down) within the bounding area of an element." I'm not familiar with the PointerEntered event but hopefully the description will help you know whether or not this is the correct event for your situation.

Comment: No! PointerPressed isn't working for me. It's making it even worse

Comment: Is [this](https://community.telligent.com/developers/w/developer85/47118.pointerstart-jquery-event) what you are talking about when you mentioned PointerStarted in your earlier comment? If it's not, then please explain exactly what you're looking for in an event (providing a link to documentation on this event would be very helpful).